# Accessing Address Book via ABAddressBookCreate

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to access address book:

```
var addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate() as! ABAddressBook!
if addressBook == nil {
    print("addressBook not available")
    return
}
var allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook)
var noOfPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook)
```

But my code always crashes on

**var allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook)**

without any error in console.

What is the right way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1: make sure you have set `Privacy - Contacts Usage Description` in plist

2: when you try to access address book, you need to have authority, here is the sample code

```
let addressStatus: ABAuthorizationStatus = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()
        if addressStatus == ABAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined {
            let addressBook: ABAddressBook? = ABAddressBookCreate().takeRetainedValue()
            if let addressBookRef = addressBook {
                ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, { (granted, error) in
                    if granted {
                        //read address book
                    } else {
                        //do something without grant, toast or alert
                    }
                })
            } else {
                //fail 
            }
        } else if addressStatus == ABAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
            //already have the authority
            let addressBook: ABAddressBook? = ABAddressBookCreate().takeRetainedValue()
            if let addressBookRef = addressBook {
                //read address book
            } else {
                //fail
            }
        } else {
            //no authority
        }
```